# How to add a Notification Scene to WatchKit target after it has been created?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, watchkit

I have already created a WatchKit Target without a notification scene, or glance scene.

Is there any way I can add either of those two scenes after the target has been created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, simply open up the `Storyboard` and drag in a `Glance`-scene and `Notification`-scene. Once you have the notification scene, you can add a `dynamic notification`-scene as well in the attributes inspector.